# class Foo::Bar vs module Foo; class Bar

Tags: ruby

Is there, under some circumstances, a difference between the following in Ruby?

```rb
class Foo::Bar
end
```

and

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example will define *Foo*.

The first example depends on a previous definition of *Foo*. It will fail if *Foo* does not exist yet.

Comment: But the first example always seem to work in Rails. How can that be? Is Rails using some sort of handler to define missing constants as modules?

Comment: No, I don't think so. And just to be sure, I tried in the rails console and received `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo`.